# Question about weird pointer

Tags: c

I study C. Digging in some C source code where I found that line. I have read about pointers, but I did not see such an example.

```
char   *uppercase (char *s);
```

What that mean ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a declaration of a function that takes a char pointer and returns a char pointer.

Answer (score 0):

```
char   *uppercase (char *s);
```

is the same as

```
char* uppercase (char *s);
```

Its return type is `char*`; it returns a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

That means that the function takes a pointer to a character and returns a pointer to a character i.e the start of the string.

Answer (score 0):

`uppercase` is afunction which returns a char type address ( that is, it can be stored in a char pointer ) as its written as `char *uppercase`...
`uppercase()` takes a char pointer as argument `char *s`...
therefore its written as `char *uppercase( char *s)`.

Answer (score 0):

In C the location of the `*` doesn't matter as long as it is somewhere between the type and name. So `char* s` is the same as `char *s` and even `char * s`.

The same applies to functions and their return types, `char* uppercase()` is equivalent to `char *uppercase()` and `char * uppercase()`.

White-space is more or less ignored in C so when writing your own code I recommend you pick one format and stick with it.

Answer (score 0):

The location of the asterisk `*` can be anywhere: between return type or function name.
It is more logical to keep it on the return type's end i.e. `char*`